# liblapack3gf imoprt error with py when running arbotix example from ROSByExample

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 1210

Groovy

When I run the very first example in ROSByExample (Fuerte) in Section 6.2 Testing the simulator, we call:

I get an error that seems to indicate that states "Import Error: liblapack.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". But I am sure I have this lib in my computer. The complete console output is:

```
started roslaunch server http://vmrg-xps-15:42951/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /arbotix/baud
 * /arbotix/controllers/base_controller/Kd
 * /arbotix/controllers/base_controller/Ki
 * /arbotix/controllers/base_controller/Ko
 * /arbotix/controllers/base_controller/Kp
 * /arbotix/controllers/base_controller/accel_limit
 * /arbotix/controllers/base_controller/base_frame_id
 * /arbotix/controllers/base_controller/base_width
 * /arbotix/controllers/base_controller/ticks_meter
 * /arbotix/controllers/base_controller/type
 * /arbotix/port
 * /arbotix/rate
 * /arbotix/read_rate
 * /arbotix/sim
 * /arbotix/sync_read
 * /arbotix/sync_write
 * /arbotix/write_rate
 * /robot_description
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    arbotix (arbotix_python/driver.py)
    odom_left_wheel_broadcaster (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    odom_right_wheel_broadcaster (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[arbotix-1]: started with pid [16038]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [16039]
[ERROR] [1364446895.621811044]: No name given for the robot.
[ERROR] [1364446895.622006176]: Could not generate robot model
[ERROR] [1364446895.622057192]: Failed to extract kdl tree from xml robot description
process[odom_left_wheel_broadcaster-3]: started with pid [16055]
process[odom_right_wheel_broadcaster-4]: started with pid [16074]
[robot_state_publisher-2] process has died [pid 16039, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher __name:=robot_state_publisher __log:=/home/vmrguser/.ros/log/062413d2-975b-11e2-b17e-c48508b13bfe/robot_state_publisher-2.log].
log file: /home/vmrguser/.ros/log/062413d2-975b-11e2-b17e-c48508b13bfe/robot_state_publisher-2*.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vmrguser/rosGWS/sandbox/ROSByExample/arbotix/arbotix_python/nodes/driver.py", line 38, in 
    from arbotix_python.diff_controller import DiffController
  File "/home/vmrguser/rosGWS/sandbox/ROSByExample/arbotix/arbotix_python/src/arbotix_python/diff_controller.py", line 38, in 
    from tf.broadcaster import TransformBroadcaster
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/__init__.py", line 29, in 
    from listener import TransformListener, TransformerROS
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/listener.py", line 34, in 
    from tf import transformations
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/transformations.py", line 174, in 
    import numpy
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in 
    import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in 
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 13, in 
    from polynomial import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 17, in 
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 48, in 
    from linalg import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 23, in 
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite
ImportError: liblapack.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[arbotix-1] process has died [pid 16038, exit code 1, cmd /home/vmrguser/rosGWS/sandbox/ROSByExample/arbotix/arbotix_python/nodes/driver.py __name:=arbotix __log:=/home/vmrguser/.ros/log/062413d2-975b-11e2-b17e-c48508b13bfe/arbotix-1.log].
log file: /home/vmrguser/.ros/log/062413d2-975b-11e2-b17e-c48508b13bfe/arbotix-1*.log
^C[odom_right_wheel_broadcaster-4] killing on exit
[odom_left_wheel_broadcaster-3] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

AND the log file contained the following output (search for ERROR towards end):

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/045318dccb15b6e89dc15ae4e3cc0b0e

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59432/liblapack3gf-imoprt-error-with-py-when-running-arbotix-example-from-rosbyexample/) by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2013-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem appears in the numpy/linalg/linalg.py module.

When I list the package using dpkg this is what i get:

```
 dpkg -l liblapack3gf 
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  liblapack3gf   3.4.1-6      all          Transitional package for liblapac
```

I tried to reinstall the lib using sudo aptitude reinstall liblapack3gf but it did not work. I tried to do it for libblas3gf but also no effect.

I uninstalled libblas* and liblapack* and then reinstalled and that seemed to have helped. But the simulator in rviz still does not show properly...

---

Originally posted by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) with karma: 208 on 2013-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0